# Error: Count y Sum devuelven valores cero. / Xamarin - SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

quisiera hacer una consulta sobre un problema que estoy teniendo. Resulta que estoy haciendo una App en Xamarin con SQLite, pero tengo un inconveniente que no me deja salir adelante y la verdad no tengo idea por que ocurre. 
Tengo dos tablas: "Clientes" y "Pedidos", necesito traer dos listas con la cantidad de pedidos por cliente y la suma de los montos de esos pedidos. Para ese trabajo uso COUNT y SUM respectivamente y GROUP BY, pero al traer la lista me trae como resultados, puros ceros, los clientes están correctamente, pero la cantidad de pedidos y las sumas solo son cero (0). 
Me genera real curiosidad porque tengo una base de datos gemela en SQL Server y ahí funciona de maravilla, pero en la App me devuelve esos valores.

Aca mis Tablas:

```
[Table("Pedidos")]
public class Pedidos
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id_Pedido { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Clientes))]
    public int Id_Cliente { get; set; }

    public DateTime Fecha_Pedido { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha_Entrega { get; set; }
    public string Entregado { get; set; }
    public int Monto { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Pedidos_Productos))]
    public List<Productos> Productos { get; set; }
}

[Table("Clientes")]
public class Clientes
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id_Cliente { get; set; }

    [Unique]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Localidad { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Saldo { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Clientes_Productos))]
    public List<Productos> Productos { get; set; }
}
```

Esta clase la uso para traer las listas:

```
public class NumeroPedidos
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int numeroPedidos { get; set; }
}
```

Aca las consultas a la base de datos:

```
    public List<NumeroPedidos> TraerNumeroPedidos()
    {
        return Conexion.Query<NumeroPedidos>("Select Clientes.Nombre, count(Pedidos.Id_Pedido) as Pedidos from Pedidos, Clientes where Clientes.Id_Cliente = Pedidos.Id_Cliente group by Clientes.Nombre").ToList();
    }

    public List<NumeroPedidos> TraerSumaPedidos()
    {
        return Conexion.Query<NumeroPedidos>("select c.Nombre, sum(p.Monto) from Clientes c, Pedidos p where c.Id_Cliente = p.Id_Cliente group by c.Nombre").ToList();
    }
```

Aca dejo una imagen de la App en tiempo de ejecución para que vean como devuelve correctamente el nombre del cliente pero el valor es cero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes colocar el mismo nombre del campo de la clase en el query

```
count(Pedidos.Id_Pedido) as Pedidos
```

Debe ser

```
count(Pedidos.Id_Pedido) as numeroPedidos
```

Al igual que el segundo query

```
sum(p.Monto) as numeroPedidos
```

También podrías cambiar el nombre del campo de la clase a numero solo o cantidad y así queda más genérico hablando de semántica, claro que habría que colocar ese nuevo nombre en los querys.

Comment: Genial Bro, hubiese estado mucho tiempo sin darme cuenta, funciona genial. Gracias.